# ArrayList of objects. Search by multiple conditions

Tags: java, arraylist

I've got an ArrayList of CRM objects (actionsList).
I want to find:
If one object has a value "First contact" in field "typeOfContact",
is there another object with the value "Offer" field "typeOfContact" and the same dealer and name as in previous object.

```
public class CRM {

    private String remark;
    private String number;
    private String dealer;
    private String name;
    private String typeOfContact;
    private String model;
    private String phone;
    private String email;
    //...

    public String getRemark(){
        return remark;
    }

    public void setRemark(String remark){
        this.remark=remark;
    }

    public String getNumber(){
        return number;
    }

    public void setNumber(String number) {
        this.number=number;
    }

    public String getDealer(){
        return dealer;
    }

    public void setDealer(String dealer) {
        this.dealer=dealer;
    }

    public String getName(){
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name=name;
    }

    public String getTypeOfContact(){
        return typeOfContact;
    }

    public void setTypeOfContact(String typeOfContact) {
        this.typeOfContact=typeOfContact;
    }

    public String getModel(){
        return model;
    }

    public void setModel(String model) {
        this.model=model;
    }

    public String getPhone(){
        return phone;
    }

    public void setPhone(String phone) {
        this.phone=phone;
    }

    public String getEmail(){
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email=email;
    }
    // ...
}
```

Should it be something like this?

```
for(CRM crm : actionsList){
   if (crm.getTypeOfContact.equals("First contact"){
      for(CRM x : actionsList){
         if (x.getDealer().equals(crm.getDealer()) && 
(x.getName().equals(crm.getName()) && x.getTypeOfContact().equals("Offer"))){
             System.out.println("OK"); 
         }
         else {
             System.out.println("Not OK"); 
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: "*Should it be something like this?*" > What happens when you run that? I'm guessing it doesn't work, otherwise you wouldn't be posting here :-)

Comment: I don't understand you question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your get methods are functions and require `()`, so this

```
if (x.getDealer.equals(crm.getDealer) && (crm.getDealer.equals(crm.getDealer) && 
    (x.getName.equals(crm.getName) && (x.getTypeOfContact.equals("Offer"){
```

And you have dangling parenthesis, and `crm.getDealer.equals(crm.getDealer)` makes no sense - so I removed that. I think you wanted something like,

```
if (x.getDealer().equals(crm.getDealer()) && 
    (x.getName().equals(crm.getName()) && x.getTypeOfContact().equals("Offer"))){
```

Comment: Thank you. Something works but not correctly. I guess the problem is in the rest of my code. Will try to solve it with fresh mind tomorrow

Comment: Thanks, everything works. Also fixed mistakes in the rest of the code